# Animate replace Detail View in UISplitViewController

Tags: objective-c, uisplitviewcontroller, transition

I have a Storyboard setup and at some point a button replaces the Detail View with another. By default, there is no transition at all: the View Controller is suddenly replaced. Can I create one and how?

My guess would to be to use a custom transition – like you normally do to have a custom animation for a view change – but I wouldn't know how to implement the “Replace” behaviour of the Split View controller.

Answer (score 2):

I did this using custom segue, when there is splitViewController, I do "show detail", otherwise I try to push/present modal. All animated. The show modal animation will fade the old controller out with transform and show the new one with transform change

```
class ShowDetailSegue: UIStoryboardSegue {

    private let showFromScale : CGFloat = 0.8
    private let hideToScale : CGFloat = 1.2
    private let animationDuration : NSTimeInterval = 0.33

    override func perform() {

        let sourceVC = self.sourceViewController as! UIViewController
        let destinationVC = self.destinationViewController as! UIViewController
        let animated = true

        if let splitVC = sourceVC.splitViewController where splitVC.isInSplitView {
            // splitview with detail is visible, we will show detail with animation
            showDetail(splitVC, sourceVC : sourceVC, destinationVC: destinationVC, animated: animated)
        } else if let navController = sourceVC.navigationController {
            // there is no split view – just push to navigation controller
            sourceVC.navigationController?.pushViewController(destinationVC, animated: animated)
        } else {
            // no navigation found, let just present modal
            sourceVC.presentViewController(destinationVC, animated: animated, completion: nil)
        }

    }

    private func showDetail(splitVC : UISplitViewController, sourceVC : UIViewController, destinationVC : UIViewController, animated : Bool) {

        let newDetailVC = GeneralNavigationController(rootViewController: destinationVC)
        newDetailVC.applyAppearance()

        if !animated {

            splitVC.showDetailViewController(newDetailVC, sender: sourceVC)

        } else {

            var currentDetailVC = splitVC.viewControllers.last as! UIViewController

            if let currentDetailNC = currentDetailVC as? UINavigationController {
                currentDetailVC = currentDetailNC.topViewController
            }

            UIView.animateWithDuration(animationDuration / 2.0, animations: { () -> Void in
                // hide the old view with transform

                currentDetailVC.view.alpha = 0
                currentDetailVC.view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(self.hideToScale, self.hideToScale)
                currentDetailVC.navigationController?.navigationBar.alpha = 0

                }, completion: { (completed) -> Void in

                    newDetailVC.navigationController?.navigationBar.alpha = 0
                    newDetailVC.view.alpha = 0
                    newDetailVC.view.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(newDetailVC.view.transform, self.showFromScale, self.showFromScale)

                    splitVC.showDetailViewController(newDetailVC, sender: sourceVC)

                    // Show new view

                    UIView.animateWithDuration(self.animationDuration / 2.0, animations: { () -> Void in

                        newDetailVC.view.alpha = 1
                        newDetailVC.view.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(newDetailVC.view.transform, 1 / self.showFromScale, 1 / self.showFromScale)

                        newDetailVC.navigationController?.navigationBar.alpha = 1

                        }, completion: { (completed) -> Void in

                            currentDetailVC.view.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(currentDetailVC.view.transform, 1 / self.hideToScale, 1 / self.hideToScale)
                    })
            })


        }


    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I used [Pavel Smejkal's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31585980/878857), with the following embellishments:

- The new detail controller may already be embedded in a
  UINavigationController, so I check for that
- I took out the references to his custom
  navigation controller class
- I converted it to Swift 3

Here is the revised code:

```
import UIKit

class SegueShowDetail: UIStoryboardSegue {

    private let showFromScale: CGFloat = 0.8
    private let hideToScale: CGFloat = 1.2
    private let animationDuration: TimeInterval = 0.33

    override func perform() {

        let sourceVC = self.source 
        let destinationVC = self.destination 
        let animated = true

        if let splitVC = sourceVC.splitViewController, !splitVC.isCollapsed {

            // splitview with detail is visible, we will show detail with animation
            showDetail( splitVC: splitVC, sourceVC : sourceVC, destinationVC: destinationVC, animated: animated )

        } else if let navController = sourceVC.navigationController {

            // there is no split view – just push to navigation controller
            sourceVC.navigationController?.pushViewController( destinationVC, animated: animated )

        } else {
            // no navigation found, let just present modal
            sourceVC.present( destinationVC, animated: animated, completion: nil )
        }

    }

    fileprivate func showDetail( splitVC : UISplitViewController, sourceVC : UIViewController, destinationVC : UIViewController, animated : Bool ) {

        var navController: UINavigationController? = destinationVC as? UINavigationController
        if nil == navController {

            navController = UINavigationController( rootViewController: destinationVC )
        }

        guard let newDetailNavVC = navController else {

            return
        }

        if !animated {

            splitVC.showDetailViewController( newDetailNavVC, sender: sourceVC )

        } else {

            var currentDetailVC = splitVC.viewControllers.last!

            if let currentDetailNC = currentDetailVC as? UINavigationController {
                currentDetailVC = currentDetailNC.topViewController!
            }

            UIView.animate(withDuration: animationDuration / 2.0, animations: { () -> Void in
                // hide the old view with transform

                currentDetailVC.view.alpha = 0
                currentDetailVC.view.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: self.hideToScale, y: self.hideToScale)
                currentDetailVC.navigationController?.navigationBar.alpha = 0

            }, completion: { (completed) -> Void in

                newDetailNavVC.navigationController?.navigationBar.alpha = 0
                newDetailNavVC.view.alpha = 0
                newDetailNavVC.view.transform = newDetailNavVC.view.transform.scaledBy( x: self.showFromScale, y: self.showFromScale )

                splitVC.showDetailViewController( newDetailNavVC, sender: sourceVC)

                // Show new view

                UIView.animate( withDuration: self.animationDuration / 2.0, animations: { () -> Void in

                    newDetailNavVC.view.alpha = 1
                    newDetailNavVC.view.transform = newDetailNavVC.view.transform.scaledBy( x: 1 / self.showFromScale, y: 1 / self.showFromScale )

                    newDetailNavVC.navigationController?.navigationBar.alpha = 1

                }, completion: { (completed) -> Void in

                    currentDetailVC.view.transform = currentDetailVC.view.transform.scaledBy( x: 1 / self.hideToScale, y: 1 / self.hideToScale)
                })
            })
        }
    }
}
```